# Video player shown with a cross mark on the Play button in iOS swift AVPLayer?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer

I am trying to play a video form my Server but when I try to do so I get a `Crossed mark` on pay button.

All other files like `.ppt`,`.keynote` etc work fine when I use them with my Server url and use a `WKWebview` to show them but `.mp4` files are not working.

**I tried 2 methods.**

1) Playing directly using WKWebview.
2) Download the file and saving it in a local path and then using `AVPlayer` to play the file.

In both cases I get same crossed mark on the play button.

```
func playVideo(url:String){

 var newUrl:String = url
 if !( url.hasPrefix("http") ||  url.hasPrefix("https") ){

 let host = kGetHostName()
 newUrl = host + newUrl
}
do 
{
let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: newUrl)!)
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("myMove.mp4")

if videoData == nil{
print("No data in this")
return
 }
 videoData?.write(toFile: path.absoluteString, atomically: true)
 let playeritem = AVPlayerItem(url: path)
 let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playeritem)
 let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
 controller.player = player
 self.present(controller, animated: true) {
 player.play()
 }
 } catch {
  print(error)
  }
```

**And when trying with WKWebview**

```
func loadWebView(url:String){

    var newUrl:String = url
    if !( url.hasPrefix("http") ||  url.hasPrefix("https") ){
        let host = kGetHostName()
        newUrl = host + newUrl
    }
     self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: newUrl)!))
}
```

Both cases fail and get this. Is there any way I can play the video without changing my `plist` settings as I want to download and play ?

**1.Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

**2.Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]